# Split 25subham2000bbsr into 4 parts in java using split

Tags: java, string, substring

How will i separate the first 2 numbers then name then pocket money Nd address in java? I have tried using Java.util.regex package but can it be done using only string package?

The string format is as follows:
1st 2 place: roll
Rest all are variable length (name, number, address) and everything without spaces

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `String.split`

Comment: `String#indexOf`, and `String#substring`. But this will cause long and ugly if statements

Comment: A) your requirements are unclear - you can always iterate a string as char sequence, or use indexOf to determine certain elements B) show us what you tried using string methods - we are not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: @ScaryWombat There is no space.. what condition should I give to split??

Comment: @GhostCat I used loops and used substring () , regex works fine but using only split; is it possible?

Comment: You need to specify the condition @SubhamPatel Say for example if the address starts with numbers, how would you differentiate the pocket money and the start of the address. Clarify your input format first. And btw, post some code if you've tried anything at all!

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. String.split() **takes** a string that represents a regular expression. The string class has various methods that accept strings representing regexes. Again, better give some examples.

Comment: @SubhamPatel You mean string into four part two strings and two number right ? For the above string ?

Comment: Yes 2 numbers 2 strings

Answer (score 0):

You can combine positive and negative lookahead to split string by position: letter is before and digit is after position to split:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String s = "ksdj23kdsjks34dkjjksd";
        String[] split = s.split("(?<=\\w)(?=\\d)");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(split));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION1**

If this is your format you can use Patterns with groups like :

```
String str = "25subham2000bbsr";
String regex = "(\\d+)([a-z]+)(\\d+)([a-z]+)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
    System.out.println(matcher.group(4));
}
```

In this regex there are 4 groups :

```
(\\d+)        -- first numbers if you need just two you can use \\{2}
([a-z]+)      -- followed by lower case alphabetical
(\\d+)        -- followed by one or more degit
([a-z]+)      -- followed by lower case alphabetical
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8Hu7wQ/1)

---

**SOLUTION2**

Another solution you can use replaceAll to separate each two number and alphabetical :

```
String str = "25subham2000bbsr";
str = str.replaceAll("(\\d)([a-z])", "$1-$2").replaceAll("([a-z])(\\d)", "$1-$2");
//str = "25-subham-2000-bbsr"
String[] spl = str.split("-");//then you can use split with -
```

**Output**

```
[25, subham, 2000, bbsr]
```

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it was done! Thanks for help! !(https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1rdP.jpg)